# Values of $w$ while $y$ changes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this is very simple, but I just can't manage to find it. I have $w, y \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Assume that $0 < y < 255$ and $500 \ge w \ge 138$. This is for an animation controlled by the scroll-top in web browser. So, when $y=1$, $w=500$ and when $y=254$, $w=138$.

I cannot find the mathematical rule to calculate $w$ using the scroll top (which is $y$). How can I do it?

Comment: If $w>500$, then how can $w=500$? Same thing for $w=138$.

Comment: Actually, it was $500>w$, but it is correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $w,y$ be reals, not naturals, you can make a straight line through the two points.  The [two-point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) is $w-500=\frac {138-500}{254-1}(y-1)$  You can simplify this for actual use, but I left the numbers in to show where they came from.  Now apply it and round to the nearest natural for $w$.